# Alternative to ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY z)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

There are plenty of questions on here regarding poor performance with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY XXX ORDER BY YYY)` but ive not been able to apply any of the answers to my scenario.

This is either a lack of understanding on my part or my scenario is not suited to this method & should be using a completely different approach.

I'm  dealing with a large amount of data (several GB), the tables break down as follows:

- **tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD**: 180,046 (Purchase Order Headers (PO's))
- **tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE**: 1,746,629 (Purchase Order Lines)
- **tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD**: 2,345,347 (Sales Order Headers (Invoices))
- **tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE**: 35,615,535 (Invoice Lines)

My requirement was to fetch 1 row per product (PRO_CODE), with the following values per product:

- Product code (PRO_CODE)
- Latest Invoice Date (SOH_DATE_ENTER)
- Latest Invoice No (DOC_NUMBER)
- Latest Invoice Account No (SLS_CODE)
- Latest Invoice Price (SOL_PRI_TRA)
- Latest PO Date (PUR_DATE)
- Latest PO No (DOC_NUMBER)
- Latest PO Account No (PUR_CODE)
- Latest PO Price (PUR_PRI_TRA)

I'm not one to ask for answers before giving it a go myself, so I gave this a go using ROW_NUMBER() but the report is taking over half an hour to run (not an exaggeration)

My tables are very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE] ( [DEPOT_CODE] [char] (10) NULL, [DOC_ID] [char] (2) NULL, [DOC_NUMBER] [char] (10) NULL, [PRO_CODE] [char] (50) NULL, [PUR_PRI_TRA] [float] NULL )
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD]  ( [DEPOT_CODE] [char] (10) NULL, [DOC_ID] [char] (2) NULL, [DOC_NUMBER] [char] (10) NULL, [PUR_CODE] [char] (20) NULL, [PUR_DATE] [datetime] NULL )
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD] ( [DEPOT_CODE] [char] (10) NULL, [DOC_ID] [char] (2) NULL, [DOC_NUMBER] [char] (10) NULL, [SLS_CODE] [char] (20) NULL, [SOH_DATE_ENTER] [datetime] NULL )
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE] ( [DEPOT_CODE] [char] (10) NULL, [DOC_ID] [char] (2) NULL, [DOC_NUMBER] [char] (10) NULL, [PRO_CODE] [char] (50) NULL, [SOL_PRI_TRA] [float] NULL )
```

I created clustered indexes to speed up the joins as follows:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE] ON [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE] ( [DEPOT_CODE] ASC, [DOC_ID] ASC, [DOC_NUMBER] ASC )
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD]  ON [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD]  ( [DEPOT_CODE] ASC, [DOC_ID] ASC, [DOC_NUMBER] ASC )
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD] ON [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD] ( [DEPOT_CODE] ASC, [DOC_ID] ASC, [DOC_NUMBER] ASC )
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE] ON [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE] ( [DEPOT_CODE] ASC, [DOC_ID] ASC, [DOC_NUMBER] ASC )
```

And this was my first attempt:

```
WITH    RawSalesData
          AS ( SELECT   Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                        Orders.SLS_CODE ,
                        Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
                        Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                        Lines.SOL_PRI_TRA ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE ORDER BY Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER DESC ) AS SaleRank
               FROM     tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
                        INNER JOIN tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                                                                                         AND Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                                                                                         AND Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
             ),
        RawPurchaseData
          AS ( SELECT   Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                        Orders.PUR_CODE ,
                        Orders.PUR_DATE ,
                        Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                        Lines.PUR_PRI_TRA ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE ORDER BY Orders.PUR_DATE DESC ) AS PurchaseRank
               FROM     tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
                        INNER JOIN tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                                                                                         AND Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                                                                                         AND Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
             ),
        ActiveProducts_All
          AS ( SELECT   PRO_CODE
               FROM     RawSalesData
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   PRO_CODE
               FROM     RawPurchaseData
             ),
        ActiveProducts
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        PRO_CODE
               FROM     ActiveProducts_All
               WHERE    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''
             )
    SELECT  ActiveProducts.PRO_CODE AS ProductCode,
            RawSalesData.SOH_DATE_ENTER AS LastSold,
            RawSalesData.DOC_NUMBER AS LastSold_OrderNo,
            RawSalesData.SLS_CODE AS LastSold_AccountNo,
            RawSalesData.SOL_PRI_TRA AS LastSold_Price,
            RawPurchaseData.PUR_DATE AS LastPurchased,
            RawPurchaseData.DOC_NUMBER AS LastPurchased_PurchaseOrderNo,
            RawPurchaseData.PUR_CODE AS LastPurchased_AccountNo,
            RawPurchaseData.PUR_PRI_TRA AS LastPurchased_Price
    FROM    ActiveProducts
            LEFT OUTER JOIN RawSalesData ON RawSalesData.PRO_CODE = ActiveProducts.PRO_CODE
                                            AND RawSalesData.SaleRank = 1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN RawPurchaseData ON RawPurchaseData.PRO_CODE = ActiveProducts.PRO_CODE
                                               AND RawPurchaseData.PurchaseRank = 1
    ORDER BY ActiveProducts.PRO_CODE
```

So my question is this: how can I adapt this query to work efficiently? If i'm flogging a dead horse with ROW_NUMBER(), what would the alternative be to meet the requirements?

To give you an idea of scale, whilst there are 40 million rows of source data here, there is only 33,000 unique products so the output from this query is relatively small in comparison to the input.

**Edit:** The Execution Plan for my 30+ minute approach looks ok (i.e. no full table scans) but I have the feeling I'm making SQL do more work than necessary:

```
  |--Parallelism(Gather Streams, ORDER BY:([Union1014] ASC))
       |--Merge Join(Right Outer Join, MANY-TO-MANY MERGE:([Lines].[PRO_CODE])=([Union1014]), RESIDUAL:([Union1014]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
            |--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1034]=(1)))
            |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1035]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER], [Expr1036]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[PUR_CODE] as [Orders].[PUR_CODE], [Expr1037]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[PUR_DATE] as [Orders].[PUR_DATE], [Expr1039]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[PUR_PRI_TRA] as [Lines].[PUR_PRI_TRA]))
            |         |--Parallelism(Distribute Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
            |              |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([Expr1034]=row_number))
            |                   |--Segment
            |                        |--Parallelism(Gather Streams, ORDER BY:([Lines].[PRO_CODE] ASC, [Orders].[PUR_DATE] DESC))
            |                             |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Lines].[PRO_CODE] ASC, [Orders].[PUR_DATE] DESC))
            |                                  |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER])=([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]), RESIDUAL:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Lines].[DEPOT_CODE]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Orders].[DEPOT_CODE] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[DOC_ID] as [Lines].[DOC_ID]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[DOC_ID] as [Orders].[DOC_ID] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
            |                                       |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
            |                                       |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD] AS [Orders]))
            |                                       |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]))
            |                                            |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE] AS [Lines]))
            |--Merge Join(Left Outer Join, MERGE:([Union1014])=([Lines].[PRO_CODE]), RESIDUAL:([Union1014]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
                 |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Union1014] ASC))
                 |    |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([Union1014]), RESIDUAL:([Union1014] = [Union1014]))
                 |         |--Concatenation
                 |              |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
                 |              |    |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([Lines].[PRO_CODE]), RESIDUAL:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE] = [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
                 |              |         |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER])=([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]), RESIDUAL:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Lines].[DEPOT_CODE]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Orders].[DEPOT_CODE] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[DOC_ID] as [Lines].[DOC_ID]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[DOC_ID] as [Orders].[DOC_ID] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                 |              |              |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                 |              |              |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD] AS [Orders]))
                 |              |              |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                 |              |                   |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE] AS [Lines]), WHERE:(ltrim(rtrim(isnull([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE],'                                                  ')))<>''))
                 |              |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
                 |                   |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([Lines].[PRO_CODE]), RESIDUAL:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE] = [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
                 |                        |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER])=([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]), RESIDUAL:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Lines].[DEPOT_CODE]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Orders].[DEPOT_CODE] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[DOC_ID] as [Lines].[DOC_ID]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[DOC_ID] as [Orders].[DOC_ID] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                 |                             |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                 |                             |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD] AS [Orders]))
                 |                             |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                 |                                  |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE] AS [Lines]), WHERE:(ltrim(rtrim(isnull([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE].[PRO_CODE] as [Lines].[PRO_CODE],'                                                  ')))<>''))
                 |--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1021]=(1)))
                      |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1022]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER], [Expr1023]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[SLS_CODE] as [Orders].[SLS_CODE], [Expr1024]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[SOH_DATE_ENTER] as [Orders].[SOH_DATE_ENTER], [Expr1026]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[SOL_PRI_TRA] as [Lines].[SOL_PRI_TRA]))
                           |--Parallelism(Distribute Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[PRO_CODE]))
                                |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([Expr1021]=row_number))
                                     |--Segment
                                          |--Parallelism(Gather Streams, ORDER BY:([Lines].[PRO_CODE] ASC, [Orders].[SOH_DATE_ENTER] DESC))
                                               |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Lines].[PRO_CODE] ASC, [Orders].[SOH_DATE_ENTER] DESC))
                                                    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER])=([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]), RESIDUAL:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Lines].[DEPOT_CODE]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[DEPOT_CODE] as [Orders].[DEPOT_CODE] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[DOC_ID] as [Lines].[DOC_ID]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[DOC_ID] as [Orders].[DOC_ID] AND [dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]=[dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[DOC_NUMBER] as [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                                                         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Orders].[DEPOT_CODE], [Orders].[DOC_ID], [Orders].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                                                         |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD] AS [Orders]))
                                                         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Lines].[DEPOT_CODE], [Lines].[DOC_ID], [Lines].[DOC_NUMBER]))
                                                              |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE].[IX_tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE] AS [Lines]))
```

SQL Fiddle with 1 PO & 1 Invoice 1 2 PRO_CODES:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/557b6/1/0

**FINAL SOLUTION PROPOSED ON BLAM & BLUE's advice:**

I basically broke the CTE down into multiple indexed temp tables, this gave the outeput in 6 minutes as opposed to 30+ minutes.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_RawSalesData
    (
      DOC_NUMBER CHAR(10) ,
      SLS_CODE CHAR(20) ,
      SOH_DATE_ENTER DATETIME ,
      PRO_CODE CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY ,
      SOL_PRI_TRA FLOAT
    )

INSERT  INTO #tbl_RawSalesData
        ( DOC_NUMBER ,
          SLS_CODE ,
          SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
          PRO_CODE ,
          SOL_PRI_TRA
        )
        SELECT  DOC_NUMBER ,
                SLS_CODE ,
                SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
                PRO_CODE ,
                SOL_PRI_TRA
        FROM    ( SELECT    Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                            Orders.SLS_CODE ,
                            Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
                            Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                            Lines.SOL_PRI_TRA ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE ORDER BY Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER DESC ) AS SaleRank
                  FROM      tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
                            JOIN tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                                                                                       AND Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                                                                                       AND Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
                ) AS RawSalesData
        WHERE   SaleRank = 1
                AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''

CREATE TABLE #tbl_RawPurchaseData
    (
      DOC_NUMBER CHAR(10) ,
      PUR_CODE CHAR(20) ,
      PUR_DATE DATETIME ,
      PRO_CODE CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY ,
      PUR_PRI_TRA FLOAT
    ) INSERT  INTO #tbl_RawPurchaseData
        ( DOC_NUMBER ,
          PUR_CODE ,
          PUR_DATE ,
          PRO_CODE ,
          PUR_PRI_TRA
        )
        SELECT  DOC_NUMBER ,
                PUR_CODE ,
                PUR_DATE ,
                PRO_CODE ,
                PUR_PRI_TRA
        FROM    ( SELECT    Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                            Orders.PUR_CODE ,
                            Orders.PUR_DATE ,
                            Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                            Lines.PUR_PRI_TRA ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE ORDER BY Orders.PUR_DATE DESC ) AS PurchaseRank
                  FROM      tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
                            INNER JOIN tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                                                                                             AND Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                                                                                             AND Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
                ) AS RawPurchaseData
        WHERE   PurchaseRank = 1
                AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''

CREATE TABLE #tbl_ActiveProducts
    (
      PRO_CODE CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
    ) INSERT  INTO #tbl_ActiveProducts
        ( PRO_CODE
        )
        SELECT  PRO_CODE
        FROM    #tbl_RawSalesData
        UNION
        SELECT  PRO_CODE
        FROM    #tbl_RawPurchaseData

SELECT  A.PRO_CODE ,
        S.SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
        S.DOC_NUMBER ,
        S.SLS_CODE ,
        S.SOL_PRI_TRA ,
        P.PUR_DATE ,
        P.DOC_NUMBER ,
        P.PUR_CODE ,
        P.PUR_PRI_TRA FROM    #tbl_ActiveProducts AS A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #tbl_RawPurchaseData AS P ON P.PRO_CODE = A.PRO_CODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #tbl_RawSalesData AS S ON S.PRO_CODE = A.PRO_CODE

DROP TABLE #tbl_ActiveProducts DROP TABLE #tbl_RawPurchaseData DROP TABLE #tbl_RawSalesData
```

Comment: Any chance of creating a sql fiddle with some sample data?  Or even include minimal table structure here, with sample data and the desired result - there might be other ways to get this instead of using row_number but without seeing what you actually need (data wise) it's kind of difficult.

Comment: Times like this I wish SSMS had a TOP X option when scripting a schema with data - will try and extract some related data for fiddle - bare with me :)

Comment: Yes, i.e. the latest PO & Invoice data PER product

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to do this in a single query?  Why not break it down into multiple queries - utilize temp tables, etc? You could get a list of all products and stick them in a temp table, do the same thing with the sales and purchase data, then optimize each of those pieces.  You might be able to even use an aggregate function to get the most recent for each `pro_code` and that *might* have better performance.  Trying to do this in a single query is a bit of overkill.

Comment: I suppose that is going to be the answer to my question, I'm just dealing with too much data & it needs to be broken down, indexed and joined more efficiently in stages. I just wanted to make sure i hadn't missed something obvious with my approach, like an index that would be useful to the window function or anything like that. Thank you for looking at it anyway.

Comment: How standard are the values in the PK fields? Does their case vary per row for what amounts to the same value (e.g. "A101" on row 1 and "a101" on row 2 that are the same "code")? Or are they consistent?

Comment: The case does vary yes, but the DB collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS so it never gives us any problems.

Comment: That is why I asked. If the case did _not_ vary, then applying a `_BIN` collation might have improved things :).

Comment: Ok, gotta ask: do you have any PK / FKs defined?

Comment: Hi Srutzky, there are no PK/FK, hence the use of clustered indexes (see the top of my question). The data & tables in question are from a 3rd party that also lack PK / FK, if there was going to be a PK / FK it would be a compound key identical to the clustered indexes ive created anyway (Uniqueness requires a combination of DEPOT_CODE, DOC_ID & DOC_NUMBER)

Comment: See tweaks in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queries are basically correct.
You problem is the CTE.
A CTE is just syntax.
Those CTEs are evaluated and most likely evaluated more than once.

A second problem is join on two condition is typically not efficient.

Materialize row 1 (and only the row 1's) into #temp tables and even declare a PK

So your join should look more  like this

```
FROM #ActiveProducts
LEFT OUTER JOIN #RawSalesData 
  ON #RawSalesData.PRO_CODE = #ActiveProducts.PRO_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN #RawPurchaseData 
  ON #RawPurchaseData.PRO_CODE = #ActiveProducts.PRO_CODE
```

P.S.  You can use CTEs to populate the #temp but don't have a CTE in the join of the final query.

you are doing a lot of stuff that I don't think is required

```
create table #RawSalesData  .. 
create table #RawPurchaseData ...    

WITH    RawSalesData
          AS ( SELECT   Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                        Orders.SLS_CODE ,
                        Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
                        Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                        Lines.SOL_PRI_TRA ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE 
                                            ORDER BY     Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER DESC ) AS SaleRank
               FROM     tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
               JOIN     tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE AS Lines  WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
                 ON     Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                AND     Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                AND     Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
             ),
        RawPurchaseData
          AS ( SELECT   Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                        Orders.PUR_CODE ,
                        Orders.PUR_DATE ,
                        Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                        Lines.PUR_PRI_TRA ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE 
                                            ORDER BY     Orders.PUR_DATE DESC ) AS PurchaseRank
               FROM     tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
               JOIN     tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK ) 
                 ON     Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                AND     Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                AND     Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
             ),

insert into #RawSalesData  ...
select ... 
from   RawSalesData 
where  RawSalesData.SaleRank = 1 
and    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''
order by RawSalesData.PRO_CODE;  -- index this column for an even faster join
insert into #RawPurchaseData  ...
select ... 
from   RawPurchaseData
where  RawPurchaseData.PurchaseRank = 1
and    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''
order by RawPurchaseData.PRO_CODE;;

    SELECT  #RawSalesData.PRO_CODE AS ProductCode,
            #RawSalesData.SOH_DATE_ENTER AS LastSold,
            #RawSalesData.DOC_NUMBER AS LastSold_OrderNo,
            #RawSalesData.SLS_CODE AS LastSold_AccountNo,
            #RawSalesData.SOL_PRI_TRA AS LastSold_Price,
            #RawPurchaseData.PUR_DATE AS LastPurchased,
            #RawPurchaseData.DOC_NUMBER AS LastPurchased_PurchaseOrderNo,
            #RawPurchaseData.PUR_CODE AS LastPurchased_AccountNo,
            #RawPurchaseData.PUR_PRI_TRA AS LastPurchased_Price
    FROM    #RawSalesData  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #RawPurchaseData  
      ON    #RawPurchaseData.PRO_CODE = #RawSalesData.PRO_CODE  
      --    now this join is trivial                                             
    ORDER BY #RawSalesData.PRO_CODE
```

tweak of revised answer

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_RawSalesData
    (
      DOC_NUMBER CHAR(10) ,
      SLS_CODE CHAR(20) ,
      SOH_DATE_ENTER DATETIME ,
      PRO_CODE CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY ,
      SOL_PRI_TRA FLOAT
    )

INSERT  INTO #tbl_RawSalesData
        ( DOC_NUMBER ,
          SLS_CODE ,
          SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
          PRO_CODE ,
          SOL_PRI_TRA
        )
        SELECT  DOC_NUMBER ,
                SLS_CODE ,
                SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
                PRO_CODE ,
                SOL_PRI_TRA
        FROM    ( SELECT    Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                            Orders.SLS_CODE ,
                            Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
                            Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                            Lines.SOL_PRI_TRA ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE ORDER BY Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER DESC ) AS SaleRank
                  FROM      tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
                            JOIN tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                                                                                       AND Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                                                                                       AND Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
                  Where     LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''
                ) AS RawSalesData
        WHERE   SaleRank = 1 
        ORDER BY PRO_CODE

CREATE TABLE #tbl_RawPurchaseData
    (
      DOC_NUMBER CHAR(10) ,
      PUR_CODE CHAR(20) ,
      PUR_DATE DATETIME ,
      PRO_CODE CHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY ,
      PUR_PRI_TRA FLOAT
    ) INSERT  INTO #tbl_RawPurchaseData
        ( DOC_NUMBER ,
          PUR_CODE ,
          PUR_DATE ,
          PRO_CODE ,
          PUR_PRI_TRA
        )
        SELECT  DOC_NUMBER ,
                PUR_CODE ,
                PUR_DATE ,
                PRO_CODE ,
                PUR_PRI_TRA
        FROM    ( SELECT    Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                            Orders.PUR_CODE ,
                            Orders.PUR_DATE ,
                            Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                            Lines.PUR_PRI_TRA ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE ORDER BY Orders.PUR_DATE DESC ) AS PurchaseRank
                  FROM      tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
                            INNER JOIN tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                                                                                            AND Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                                                                                            AND Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
                  Where     LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''
                ) AS RawPurchaseData
        WHERE   PurchaseRank = 1
        ORDER BY PRO_CODE


SELECT  isnull (P.PRO_CODE, S.PRO_CODE)
        S.SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
        S.DOC_NUMBER ,
        S.SLS_CODE ,
        S.SOL_PRI_TRA ,
        P.PUR_DATE ,
        P.DOC_NUMBER ,
        P.PUR_CODE ,        
        FROM            #tbl_RawPurchaseData AS P 
        FULL OUTER JOIN #tbl_RawSalesData    AS S ON S.PRO_CODE = P.PRO_CODE

DROP TABLE #tbl_ActiveProducts DROP TABLE #tbl_RawPurchaseData DROP TABLE #tbl_RawSalesData
```

Comment: Tricky as you cant put a WHERE clause on a window function, so i'd still need to use a CTE / Derived table to populate the temp tables. Ill give it a go & see if it's any faster.

Comment: Please test this out.  I am not making this up.  I do something very much like this in production.

Comment: Hi Blam, ive edited my answer with my interpretation of what your saying. It does perform better & now only takes 5 minutes as opposed to 30. That 5 minutes is still spent crunching the ROW_NUMBER()'s though :'( Feedback welcome :)

Comment: 5 is way better than 30.  You have to do the ugly stuff once.  At least here is does it once.  Work on tuning that partition by.  I don't agree you need a #tbl_ActiveProducts but that might not make much diffence in the time.  I agree you HeavenCore that you can mover that where up.  And an index on PRO_CODE will make a world of difference!

Comment: @HeavenCore - Really?  from 30 to 5 and that is not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

One conceptual problem, regardless of anything else: You are JOINing, etc, from your largest table, sorting it for the ROW_NUMBER (i.e. the PARTITION BY part), etc and *then* filtering on it?  You have the following in a sub-cte:

```
  ActiveProducts
      AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    PRO_CODE
           FROM     ActiveProducts_All
           WHERE    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''
         )
```

This WHERE condition needs to be applied to the two base CTEs: `RawSalesData` and `RawPurchaseData` and then just remove the WHERE from this CTE.

```
RawSalesData
      AS ( SELECT   Orders.DOC_NUMBER ,
                    Orders.SLS_CODE ,
                    Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER ,
                    Lines.PRO_CODE ,
                    Lines.SOL_PRI_TRA ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Lines.PRO_CODE
                                   ORDER BY Orders.SOH_DATE_ENTER DESC ) AS SaleRank
           FROM     tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD AS Orders WITH ( NOLOCK )
           INNER JOIN tbl_SynergyCache_SOL_LINE AS Lines WITH ( NOLOCK )
                   ON Lines.DEPOT_CODE = Orders.DEPOT_CODE
                  AND Lines.DOC_ID = Orders.DOC_ID
                  AND Lines.DOC_NUMBER = Orders.DOC_NUMBER
           WHERE    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(PRO_CODE, ''))) <> ''
         )
 ....
 ActiveProducts
     AS ( SELECT DISTINCT PRO_CODE
          FROM     ActiveProducts_All
        )
```

---

Also, regardless of any changes I have suggested or that you have implemented from @Blam's answer, you would be well served to do the following:

- Define PK and FKs on the tables (if none of the 3 key fields have NULLs; they are defined as NULL but that doesn't mean they contain NULLs, but you would have to ALTER the columns as well to be NOT NULL):

  - Even if the source is 3rd party, knowing of the relationship between them helps the optimizer.
  - Also knowing that the value of the Key (even if just a CLUSTERED INDEX and not a PK) is unique also helps the optimizer. So even if you don't want to do the PK (or if you can't due to there being some NULL values in these 3 Key fields), at least re-define the CLUSTERED INDEX as being UNIQUE (on the two Header tables)
- Create non-clustered indexes to support the sorting of the PARTITION BY and ORDER BY operations:

  - tbl_SynergyCache_PUR_ORD.PUR_DATE DESC
  - tbl_SynergyCache_SOH_HEAD.SOH_DATE_ENTER DESC
- And, prior to doing any of the PK/FK changes, it seems that the 3 key fields--DEPOT_CODE, DOC_ID & DOC_NUMBER--are only used for JOINs and not sorting. Meaning, you are joining on three case-insensitive string fields (not good). ALL queries joining these tables would benefit by the addition of an INT NOT NULL IDENTITY field on the Header tables and an INT NOT NULL field to hold the matching value in the Detail tables. These new INT fields would be the CLUSTERED PK in the Header tables and CLUSTERED INDEX (can't be unique so can't be PK) in the detail tables.

Comment: Reason for downvote? Did I forget to shower today or something?

Comment: I did not vote you down but I don't think that is correct.  This may move ROW_NUMBER() to a different line and change the results.

Comment: I didn't downvote this either :'( I share your annoyance with that! In regards to your answer, Where I do the PRO_CODE where clause (on the ActiveProducts_All CTE), there is 33,000 rows, doing it in the RawSalesData CTE as you suggest would be applying the where cause to 40,000,000 rows? I don't see how that would be any faster? Also, this clause only removes 100 rows at the very most so its a bit of a moot point im afraid :'(

Comment: @Blam : I was about to agree with your point but then I took another look and the PARTITION BY is on Lines.PRO_CODE, so the NULL and empty string values are already being thrown out as entire groups and removing them at this stage wouldn't alter the final results, right?

Comment: @HeavenCore Ok, fair enough that it wouldn't do that much good, but the idea was that if it did remove a decent amount of rows then it would reduce the effort on the sort operation(s) and JOINs. In that case I think it would be better to do earlier in the process. Besides, its not like the number of rows is reduced by the time you get to that sub-cte ;-)

Comment: But a Lines.PRO_CODE of 'space' will survive the partition by.  So it would in that case move the RowNumber.

Comment: @Blam Correct. But those lines of ' ' will be a) grouped together via the PARTITION BY, and then b) removed entirely by that WHERE condition in the `ActiveProducts` cte. Hence removing the rows earlier in the process doesn't change the ROW_NUMBER values for any rows having non-NULL, non-empty, non-only-spaces `PRO_CODE`.

Comment: @HeavenCore Please see the edits I put at the bottom of my answer, the suggestions. The last one in particular--adding the INT fields to support the JOINs--should speed things up considerably in addition to how far Blam's suggestion has improved things.